# What does variable container mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

“In other words, an LHS look-up is done when a variable appears on the lefthand side of an assignment operation, and an RHS look-up is done when a variable appears on the righthand side of an assignment operation.
Actually, let’s be a little more precise. An RHS look-up is indistinguishable, for our purposes, from simply a look-up of the value of some variable, whereas the LHS look-up is trying to find the **variable container** itself, so that it can assign.”

Excerpt From: Kyle Simpson. “Scope and Closures.” iBooks.

Here I confuse with term "variable container".

Comment: Where did you see the term "variable container"? Can you [edit] your question to include the original sentence (or paragraph)? I guess you could say that a variable is a container for a *value*.

Comment: i'm reading one book of js and there if found it

Comment: What book? I've never heard of a "variable container" before, so it's likely something your book defines.

Comment: "lhs lookup is trying to find the variable container" what does this container means ?

Comment: scope and closures by kyle simpson

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show that sentence in context. I.e., quote the whole paragraph.